# How to upload a quakeml file using PHP?

Tags: php, file-upload

I am  trying to upload a quakeml file type format. It needs to be stored in a directory via a form but it does not upload anything. I have already written this code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <body>
    <?php
       if(isset($_FILES['file'])){

          $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
          $file_size =$_FILES['file']['size'];
          $file_tmp =$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
          $file_type=$_FILES['file']['type'];
          $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['file']['name'])));

          $expensions= array("quakeml");

          if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
             $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a quakeml";
          }

          if($file_size > 4097152) {
             $errors[]='File size must be excately 4 MB';
          }

          if(empty($errors)==true) {
             move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads/".$file_name);
             echo "Success";
          }else{
             print_r($errors);
          }
      }
    ?>

          <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
             <input type="file" name="file" />
             <input type="submit" value="upload" />
          </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Why is the above not uploading anything?

Comment: What is the error that you have ?

Comment: nothing is uploaded @georoot